# Unity 2018: Open an external process

Tags: unity-game-engine, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to start a process from unity. It should sync the streaming assets folder with a folder present in an http server.

Everything works well but it creates a streaming assets folder outside the "projectName_Data" folder.

I'm using this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class refreshVideo : MonoBehaviour {

public string processName;

public void startRefresh(string ipServer)
{
    // Create a process
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    // Set the StartInfo of process
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = Application.dataPath + "/" + processName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = ipServer;
    path = Application.dataPath;
    // Start the process
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

}

The process is inside the dataPath and if I start it manually it sync the streaming assets folder without problems. If unity starts it, it seams to start it from outside the dataPath.

Can I tell to Unity to open the exteral exe from the dataPath folder?

Comment: When you run it manually perhaps you are starting it from a starting folder, given you never set the start folder

Comment: I thought you can't write to streaming assets at runtime?

Comment: @frankhermes I think you can...

Comment: @BugFinder how can I set the starting folder?

Comment: And people wonder why SO gets crappy.. workingfolder is a property of startinfo